# Where to put a code to execute on every Laravel request?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm building a PHP app using Laravel Framework. I need to read some session values on every request and use this values on my controller methods.

How can I achieve this? Where to put this code?

I would like something like the Zend Framework Bootstrap class.

Comment: You can use `Config::set('foo' => 'bar')` in a service provider and `Config::get('foo')` will be available everywhere. If you use multidimensional arrays to set the values, you can grab them with dot notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you can create a file named, for instance, `BaseController.php` which extends `Controller`. Then put your logic in the `__construct()`

Then, all of your other controllers can extend `BaseController` and in their `__construct()` they can perform a `parent::__construct();` to make that fire.

Answer (score 4):

The best practice is to use the Laravel Request Lifecycle (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/lifecycle)

Following the documentation, the best place to place "onLoad" or global code, is on the boot method of the appServiceProvider. For example, if I wan't to set an specific timezone for all my project:

```
//app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
/**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Jujuy');
    }
```